# How To get User's email by user's screen name in linqToTwitter?

Tags: c#, twitter, linq-to-twitter

I want to get user's email by user's screen name in linqToTwitter, I use this Code:

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    CredentialStore = new SingleUserInMemoryCredentialStore
    {
            ConsumerKey = "<Twitter consumer key>",
            ConsumerSecret = "<Twitter consumer secret>",
            AccessToken = "<Your access token>",
            AccessTokenSecret = "<Your access token secret>"
    }
};

var objTwitter = new TwitterContext(auth);
var objAccount = (from account in objTwitter.User
                  where account.Type == UserType.Show &&
                      account.ScreenName == sUser
                  select account);

var user = objAccount.SingleOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine("UserName       : " + user.ScreenName);
Console.WriteLine("Name           : " + user.Name);
Console.WriteLine("UserID         : " + user.UserIDResponse);
Console.WriteLine("CreatedAt      : " + user.CreatedAt);
Console.WriteLine("# of Friends   : " + user.FriendsCount);
Console.WriteLine("# of Followers : " + user.FollowersCount);
Console.WriteLine("Email          : " + user.Email);
Console.WriteLine("# of Tweets    : " + user.StatusesCount);
Console.WriteLine("Photo URL      : " + user.ProfileImageUrl);
Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
```

but user's email is null.

Comment: maybe the email is in fact null? If it's getting that far without throwing an exception, it must be finding a record to populate your `user` object, and the record that is returned does not have an associated email.

Comment: but my twitter account has email

Comment: When you say the email is `null`, what exactly happens? Is an exception thrown? Is `objAccount` populated with a collection of `objTwitter.User` objects? Is `user` populated?

Comment: yes user populated but the email is empty.

Comment: When you check the `user` object do the other properties contain the values you expect, i.e. is the record selected the record that is expected? Does the `objAccount` contain more than one result? What type is `user.Email`? What I am trying to get at is that either you are selecting the wrong record, or else the email is not actually populated.

Comment: yes, the user properties are the ones expected I check it. but the user.Email has null value

Comment: and what does that tell you?

Comment: I am not understand.

Comment: if all the details are correct, if only one result is returned, and it is the correct result, but the email is null, then that means there is no email address to show.

Comment: my question is why user's email is null although my twitter account has an email address

Comment: How am i or anyone else supposed to know? How do you know that the database record has an email address? Have you looked at the database? are you pulling back the right record?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Twitter VerifyCredentials Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials), you need to be whitelisted to receive email addresses. Otherwise, they are null.

That said, your query won't work because LINQ to Twitter is async and you should have written the materialization statement like this:

```
var user = await objAccount.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Notice the `await` modifier and `Async` suffix on `SingleOrDefault`. Because it is async, your entire call chain needs to be async.

Once you are whitelisted, by Twitter, you should query `AccountType.VerifyCredentials`, like this:

```
        try
        {
            var verifyResponse =
                await
                (from acct in twitterCtx.Account
                 where acct.Type == AccountType.VerifyCredentials &&
                       acct.IncludeEmail == true
                 select acct)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

            if (verifyResponse != null && verifyResponse.User != null)
            {
                User user = verifyResponse.User;

                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Email for {user.ScreenNameResponse} is {user.Email}."); 
            }
        }
        catch (TwitterQueryException tqe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tqe.Message);
        }
```

BTW, you should re-key your application as soon as possible. I edited it to remove your credentials from the code, but they're still in the diff and many people can find them and write code on Twitter as if they were you.